# How to run useEffect once and update data to useState before mounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to call an API when the component mounts once. However, I can't do that without editing it to update the state after, as follows;

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

const fetchData = async () => { 
  const data = await fetch(...)
  setValue(data)
}
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData()
}, [value]) // updating value useState
```

If I do that, I hit the API limit. The intended usage is for value to be updated but also run once.

Comment: Why is `value` a dependency there? (Also shouldn't that be `setValue(data)`?)

Comment: You have an infinite loop. You fetch the data, update `value`, the effect watches for changes in `value` makes a new request, updates `value`, then the effect runs again etc. Just remove `value` from the dependency array so it's `[]`.

Comment: If I remove `value` from the dependency array, the value doesn't update in my component.

Comment: Depends how you're logging it. State updates are async so you can't immediately log them. Add a separate useEffect with `value` in the dependency array to see it working: `useEffect(() => console.log(value), [value]);`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has been said in the comments (the dependencies array should be left empty), you should also be mindful that [React Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) will mount every component twice, to try and catch some bugs. This is done only in development mode and has no effect in production.

I would recommend you placing some `console.log`s in the component hooks and body to get a good idea of what function is being invoked and when.